# Install g++ for specific version of Debian

Tags: linux, g++, debian, platform-specific

I've gotten a place of equipment from a supplier and it uses an old version of Debian Linux - I would like to install g++ on it so I can compile locally a program I'm using on other platforms (I understand the process of cross-compiling is complex and difficult).

However, I don't what apt-get to update any components on the device as there are hardware specific drivers/applications that have been provided by the manufacturer. How can I tell apt-get to install whatever version of g++ is already compatible with the OS?

Thanks for your help.

Edit:
I should add, the platform has a MIPS processor, which I don't see in the -arch options. Thanks for the help so far though.

Also, for the possibly of cross-compiling, I'm going from a Ubuntu laptop to the MIPS debian system.

Comment: You don't need a specific G++ version. You need the correct compiler flags and libraries to build for the hardware present. But you should be able to use the latest versions of those tools. (For example, you may need to compile with `-m32 -arch=pentium` and you may need to build glibc with  `-enable_kernel=2.6.0` and so on.)

Answer (score 1):

check it may work

```
apt-get install gcc g++ gfortran
```